# AngularJS: complicated form performance?

Tags: performance, forms, angularjs

A target SPA is suppose to have few very complicated forms (say, up to 30 controls in some forms). Let's skip discussion about bad practice to use such forms - I'm agree with you :)
The form is a filter to get data from server and present it in paginated list (or table) with sorting. Target clients are from desktop to tablets.

In some discussion I have met an opinion AngularJS architecture isn't suitable for such complicated forms. In particular, this opinion was motivated by the fact, that high fields amount results in big computation work as far as AngularJS polls all the fields (binds) on any event.

Is the conclusion valid?

In opposite case - do you know hrefs of examples of complicated forms running under AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends largely on what you're trying to do with that form in terms of validation.  If you're performing potentially complex validation tasks on a form with a lot of inputs then you may find it's not suitable.  However, although this is anecdotal, I've personally not had any issues with complex forms with complex validation.

I don't think I can help much more without some more information on what potential angular issues were used to justify this opinion.

Comment: So I must count fields with live validation rather fields themselves, thanks!